# How to mount a flat screen TV above a fireplace?

Tags: electrical, wiring, fireplace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should I run wiring for my above-fireplace mounted TV?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/11311/how-should-i-run-wiring-for-my-above-fireplace-mounted-tv)

I have a flat screen TV on a wall mount that I'd like to move to the brick above the fireplace (which is only lit maybe 4 times a year).

Two questions: Since the brick never gets warm at all, can heat exiting the fireplace itself & rising into the room damage the electronics even if there is a mantle below it deflecting the heat?

Also, how could I run all of the wiring & cables to be hidden similarly to how I have them run inside the wall now?

Comment: Possible duplicates: [mounting on brick](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5672/mount-an-lcd-tv-to-30-year-old-masonry-fireplace) and [running wiring over the fireplace](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/11311/how-should-i-run-wiring-for-my-above-fireplace-mounted-tv?rq=1)

Comment: I know that mounting a TV over a fireplace looks cool, but are you sure that's going to be a comfortable position for watching? You're going to have a lot of neck strain from looking up. I like to have the center of my TVs about at eye level when seated, or maybe slightly higher.